# The relation between eigenvalues, row operations, and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

The following statements seem true:

1. Row operations will change eigenvalues.
2. Row operations will in general change the column space.
3. The eigenvectors of non-zero eigenvalues span the column space.
4. The eigenvectors of zero eigenvalue span the null space.

If so, my question is what relationship can be drawn between the eigenvalues, eigenvectors, column space, and the null space?

For example, according to 1, 2 and 3, does the change of the column space will change eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of the non-zero eigenvalues?

Comment: Note that when you perform elementary row operations (there are three known elementary row operations) each one affects the determinant of the matrix in a certain way and remember that when you find the eigenvalues, you are finding out when the determinant $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ so if you decided to multiply the matrix by some scalar, then your eigenvalues will definitely change.

Comment: 3 is false. The $2\times 2$ real matrix corresponding to a rotation by $90$ degrees has no eigenvalues, so the span of the eigenvectors of nonzero eigenvalues is trivial, but the column space is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Even for matrices with a full set of eigenvalues, e.g., $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)$, the span of the eigenvectors is just the vectors $(x,0)^T$, but the columnspace is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: In fact 3 is true if and only if the characteristic polynomial splits, and each nonzero eigenvalue satisfies that its geometric and algebraic multiplicities are equal.

Comment: Thanks you all!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Bit of a random question on an old thread, but is "each nonzero eigenvalue satisfies that its geometric and algebraic multiplicities are equal" the same thing as saying the matrix is diagonalisable?

Comment: @VJ123 not necessarily, because zero could be an eigenvalue, and the multiplicities may fail to match for zero.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for your prompt reply! Ah I think I get you. So for a matrix to be diagonalisable, geometric and algebraic multiplicities of ALL eigenvalues must match. For (3) to be satisfied, they need to match only for the non-zero eigenvalues. So if a matrix is diagonalisable, then (3) is automatically satisfied. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @VJ123 That matches what I said, but it may be incorrect. The claim holds vacuously for $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right)$, and clearly the "eigenvectors corresponding to nonzero eigenvalue" do not span the columnspace, because that span is trivial.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with what it means for a claim to hold "vacuously". Could you please elaborate so I can better understand what you're saying?

Comment: @VJ123 an implication in which the antecedent is always false is itself true. So a statement like "for all $x$, if $x$ is an element of the empty set, the $x$ is blue" is true 'vacuously' because the premise ("$x$ is an element of the empty set") is never true, so the implication is always true.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah I see. All right, thanks for your responses and elaboration!